# Why I can't get return value in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, promise

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :options.sync="options"
      :server-items-length="totalDesserts"
      :loading="loading"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')
  const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    hosts: ['localhost:9200'],
  })
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        totalDesserts: 0,
        desserts: [],
        loading: true,
        options: {},
        headers: [...],
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        handler () {
          this.getDataFromApi()
        },
        deep: true,
      },
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getDataFromApi()
    },
    methods: {
      getDataFromApi () {
        this.loading = true
        this.fakeApiCall().then(data => {
          this.desserts = data.items
          this.totalDesserts = data.total
          this.loading = false
        })
      },
      /**
       * In a real application this would be a call to fetch() or axios.get()
       */
      fakeApiCall () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options
          let items = this.GetList(1)
          console.log(items.then(rs => { return rs }))
          items.then(console.log)
          const total = items.length

          if (sortBy.length === 1 && sortDesc.length === 1) {
            items = items.sort((a, b) => {
              const sortA = a[sortBy[0]]
              const sortB = b[sortBy[0]]

              if (sortDesc[0]) {
                if (sortA < sortB) return 1
                if (sortA > sortB) return -1
                return 0
              } else {
                if (sortA < sortB) return -1
                if (sortA > sortB) return 1
                return 0
              }
            })
          }

          if (itemsPerPage > 0) {
            items = items.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage)
          }

          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
              items,
              total,
            })
          }, 1000)
        })
      },
      async GetList (day) {
        const result = await client.search({...})
        // console.log(result)
        if (result.hits.total.value > 0) {
          const RsList = new Array(result.hits.hits.length)
          for (let x = 0; x < result.hits.hits.length; x++) {...}
          // console.log(RsList)
          return RsList
        } else {
          throw new Error('no result')
        }
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

I write this code.(It from Vuetify example code:https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort)

GetList function return array for table.

But when It run **this.GetList(1)** return Promise object.

[chrome debugging image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buyOS.png)

Even add then(`this.GetList(1).then(rs => {return rs}`) It's not work....

How can I get return array from GetList?

Comment: Is the `fakeApiCall` only a fake for the purpose of this question? If yes, why do you have a problem with that, shouldn't your real code just do a simple `fetch()` call?

Comment: Ah it not fake code. I just copy n paste example code for find out how example code work and add some my code.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't. `fakeApiCall` was meant to be completely replaced by a real API call. You absolutely need to get rid of the `new Promise` and the `setTimeout`, they were meant only as an example of a data-returning promise. You already have `GetList()` for that.

Comment: U right, after changing fakeApiCall to async fuction. It's work!
Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess mixing fakeApiCall's Promise and async GetList is problem.
So, After changing fakeApiCall to async fuction. It's work! Bergi!!

Answer (score 1):

Since GetList method is an async, it return a promise.
With a promise you can choose two ways:

- use `items.then(e => /*something*/)` like the example in the console.log
- put an await before the method call `const items = await this.GetList(1)`

This should work